# Adding HTML classes to .tag files?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am currently attempting to add an HTML class to a span tag within a .tag file. Currently when I do so, it breaks pretty much everything on my page. Wondering if this is possible with some special formatting?

```
<c:choose>
    <%-- If the author has a slug, assume that they should have an author page --%>
    <c:when test="${not empty element.slug}">
         <c:set var="formatted_credit" value="${formatted_credit}<a href=\"/author/${element.slug}/\"><span>${byline}</span></a><span>${authorBeat}</span>${!status.last ? ', ' : ''}" />
    </c:when>
    <%-- Otherwise just show the authors name --%>
    <c:otherwise>
         <c:set var="formatted_credit" value="${formatted_credit}<span>${byline}</span><span>${authorBeat}</span>${!status.last ? ', ' : ''}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I'm trying to add (class="author-beat") to my ${authorBeat} spans,
but as I stated, it brings a host of errors.

Comment: Why couldn't you add a css class to an HTML element? Of course you can. What happens **precisely** when you do?

Comment: I'm using PageBuilder, (a tool within the Washington Post's Arc Suite) to build a particular article template for the news org I work for. When I attempt to put a class on the span within this .tag file, it breaks almost all the features on this page, with errors ranging from missing "=" all of a sudden 

***org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/features/global/most-read/feature.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.arc.credit_tag cannot be resolved to a type.***

Works fine without the class. Not sure why.